# IPython Notebook stuck at login

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have an IPython notebook server running on a BeagleBone Black (not sure if relevant).

When I try to log in to the server at

```
http://192.168.7.2:8888
```

I get the login screen, but after I enter my pass word and click "Log In" nothing happens.

I noticed that if I put in the wrong password, I get the message "Invalid Password", so I know I am putting in the correct password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have error message in the terminal that launched IPython, of in the javascript console in your browser ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  If I just make up some page (http://192.168.7.2:8888/madeuppage), then I can get 404 not found error on the terminal and the console, but if I'm just logging in, I get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over this. Solution was to allow cookies.